SwiftData - Cannot convert value of type 'PredicateExpressions.Equal<PredicateExpressions.KeyPath<PredicateExpressions.Variable<Array<Todo>.Element>
I receive the below error when trying to init a SwiftData query in a view:
 Error: Cannot convert value of type 'PredicateExpressions.Equal<PredicateExpressions.KeyPath
<PredicateExpressions.Variable<Array<Todo>.Element>, Int>, PredicateExpressions.KeyPath<PredicateExpressions.Value<Section>, 
Int>>'(aka'PredicateExpressions.Equal<PredicateExpressions.
KeyPath<PredicateExpressions.Variable<Todo>, Int>, PredicateExpressions.KeyPath<PredicateExpressions.Value<Section>, 
Int>>') to closure result type 'any StandardPredicateExpression<Bool>'

TodoView.swift
import SwiftUI
import SwiftData

struct TodoView: View {
    
    @Query var todos: [Todo]
    
    @EnvironmentObject var currentSection: Section
    
    @Environment(\.modelContext) var modelContext
    
    var DWMY = ["D","W","M","Y"]
    
    var body: some View {
        List {
            ForEach(todos) { todo in
                HStack {
                    if todo.completed == false {
                        Text("[ ]")
                    } else {
                        Text("[X]")
                    }
                    Text(todo.name)
                    Text(DWMY[todo.section])
                }
            }
            .onDelete(perform: deleteToDo)
        }
        .navigationBarTitleDisplayMode(.inline)
    }
    
    init(todoSection: Section) {
        _todos = Query(filter: #Predicate { todo in
            todo.section == currentSection.section
        })
    }
    
    func deleteToDo(at offsets: IndexSet ) {
           for offset in offsets {
               let todo = todos[offset]
               modelContext.delete(todo)
           }
    }
}

The error occurs when I try to give the query the value currentSection.section if I replace currentSection.section with a hard coded Int there are no errors.
From what I have read this is happening because my Environment is not passed down to ToDoView.swift until Body is created so currentSection.section does not exist when init occurs.
What is the correct way to pass  my currentSection.section value into init?

You cannot use currentSection.section in #Predicate. Declare a let constant first, then replace currentSection.section with that.

@Sweeper I have tried that but that gives me a Thread 1: Fatal error: No ObservableObject of type Section found. A View.environmentObject(_:) for Section may be missing as an ancestor of this view. error.

I see. So what's the todoSection parameter doing? It seems unused.

I don't really know heh!  I have tried using something like todoSection: Int = 0 to give it a default value also, but that doesn't really change the errors.

You could try to do what you have in init(..) in .onAppear{..}, to ensure that currentSection is available at the time.

@workingdogsupportUkraine - Where / what would I attach that .onAppear{} to?

try outside the List

Query doesn’t currently support dynamically changing hit predicate so you might want to fallback to core data and @FetchRequest for this View

I would make TodoView not depend on the environment object for creating the Query. Have the init take in the section number.
struct TodoView: View {
    @Query var todos: [Todo]

    // you could still have the EnvironmentObject here for other purposes, just not for creating the query
    // @EnvironmentObject var currentSection: Section
    
    init(sectionNumber: Int) {
        _todos = Query(filter: #Predicate { todo in
                    todo.section == sectionNumber
                })
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        List(todos) { todo in
            Text(todo.name)
            // ...
        }
    }
}

Then get the EnvironmentObject in the parent view:
struct TodoWrapper: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var currentSection: Section

    var body: some View {
        TodoView(sectionNumber: currentSection.section)
    }
}


I finally figured this out before seeing your answer. I wasn't passing currentSection.section to the ToDoView at all. Thanks!
